# Intent Object show null After sending data to other activity

Tags: java, android

I am facing problem while sending data through `Intent`.

Let's say I have two Activities :

1. Personal Information
2. Documentational Information.

What I am doing: When user fills all the given edit text fields and clicks save I send all the data through intent to the 3rd activity and now user is in the documentational activity, enters data and hits save, and data is transferred to the 3rd Activity.

The problem is in the **3rd Activity**: I only get data based on the latest activity - I mean if user first enters personal info and then documentational info, I only get data of doucumentational activity and vice versa.

I am building an app that can get data from the user and show it in a pdf file

**personal info activity :**

```
public void getting_data_from_fields_and_sending_on_click_listner () {

        radio_Group_Martial_Status.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                martial_status = radioButton.getText().toString() ;

            }
        });

        Intent sendingData = new Intent (Personal_Information_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class);
        sendingData.putExtra("FirstName" , fullName.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("Born" , born.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("Nationality" , nationality.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("CurrentPlace" , currentPlace.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("Address" , address.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("PhoneNumber" , phoneNumber.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("EmailAddress" , emailAddress.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("SelfIntro" , selfIntro.getText().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("Day" ,  day.getSelectedItem().toString());
        sendingData.putExtra("Month" , month.getSelectedItem().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("Year" , year.getSelectedItem().toString() );
        sendingData.putExtra("MartialStatus" , martial_status);

        startActivity(sendingData);
}
```

**doc info activity**

```
private void getting_data_from_fields_and_sending_on_click_listner() {

        Intent sendingData = new Intent (Documentation_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class);

        String passportIssueDate = passportIssueM.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+passportIssueY.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String idCardIssueDate = idIssueM.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+idIssueY.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String licenceIssueDate = licenceIssueM.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+licenceIssueY.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String passportExpiryDate =  passportExpiryM.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+passportExpiryY.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String idCardExpiryDate =  idExpiryM.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+idExpiryY.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String licenceExpiryDate =  licenceExpiryM.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+licenceExpiryY.getSelectedItem().toString();

        sendingData.putExtra("PassportNumeber" , passportNumber.getText().toString());
        sendingData.putExtra("IdCard" , idCardNumber.getText().toString());
        sendingData.putExtra("Licence" , licenceNumebr.getText().toString());

        sendingData.putExtra("PID"  , passportIssueDate);
        sendingData.putExtra("PED"  , passportExpiryDate);
        sendingData.putExtra("IID"  , idCardIssueDate);
        sendingData.putExtra("IED"  , idCardExpiryDate);
        sendingData.putExtra("LID"  , licenceIssueDate);
        sendingData.putExtra("LED"  , licenceExpiryDate);

        startActivity(sendingData);
    }
```

**3rd activity**

```
    public void gettingInfoFromTheDocumentationalInformationActivity() {    

        passportNumber =  getInformation.getStringExtra("PassportNumeber");
        passportIssue =  getInformation.getStringExtra("PID");
        passportExpiry =  getInformation.getStringExtra("PED");
        idNumebr =  getInformation.getStringExtra("IdCard");
        idIssue =  getInformation.getStringExtra("IID");
        idExpiry =  getInformation.getStringExtra("IED");
        licenceNumebr =  getInformation.getStringExtra("Licence");
        licenceIssue =  getInformation.getStringExtra("LID");
        licenceExpiry =  getInformation.getStringExtra("LED");
    }

    public void gettingInfoFromThePersonalInformationActivity() {

        fullName = getInformation.getStringExtra("FirstName");
        born = getInformation.getStringExtra("Born");
        nationality = getInformation.getStringExtra("Nationality");
        currentLocation = getInformation.getStringExtra("CurrentPlace");
        address = getInformation.getStringExtra("Address");
        emailAddress = getInformation.getStringExtra("EmailAddress");
        selfInfo = getInformation.getStringExtra("SelfIntro");
        phoneNumber = getInformation.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
        day = getInformation.getStringExtra("Day");
        month = getInformation.getStringExtra("Month");
        year = getInformation.getStringExtra("Year");
        martialStatus = getInformation.getStringExtra("MartialStatus");
    }

    private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException 
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        String output = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mypdf.pdf";

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(output));

        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph("Name : " +fullName));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Date of Birth : "+ day+"-"+month+"-"+year));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Birth Place : " +born));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Nationality : " + nationality));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Current Place : " +currentLocation));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Martial Status : " + martialStatus));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Address : " + address));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Phone Number : " +phoneNumber));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Email : " + emailAddress));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Self Introduction : " + selfInfo));
        document.add(new Paragraph("__________________________________"));

        document.add(new Paragraph("Passport Number : " + passportNumber));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Issue Date : " +passportIssue));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Expiry Date : " + passportExpiry));
        document.add(new Paragraph("ID Card Number  : " + idNumebr));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Issue Date : " +idIssue));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Expiry Date : " + idExpiry));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Licence Number  : " + licenceNumebr));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Issue Date : " +licenceIssue));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Expiry Date : " + licenceExpiry));

        document.close();
}
```

Comment: First of all, I don't need this code to see that you have wrong assumption about how async code and callbacks work. You only assign the `martial_status` in click callback, but you use it outside of click handling. Anyway, I'd like to see a [mcve] to confirm I didn't miss anything.

Comment: What is `getInformation` here ?

Comment: I assume "getInformation" is the intent, where are you declaring this?

Comment: Intent getInformation = getIntent() ; @ADM

Comment: even if i remove that block of code i.e radio_group_martial_Status .. there is still a prob .. @M.Prokhorov ..Actually it just set the intent to null as i mention as latest activity condition .. BTW thanks for your time

Comment: @SaadZahoor, that's because you don't need to *re*move it. You need to *move* it elsewhere. It's not related. And you also need to think what would happen if user *didn't* change anything in radio group: listener wouldn't fire, and you'll be left with initial value of the variable. Since your code compiles, then I assume that variable is an instance variable of activity, and its initial value is `null`.

Comment: wait are yuo saying you expect data from the first two activities to present on the third?

Comment: if i save personal activity first and the doc i get this pdf .. https://48h.pics/SirkaS30

Comment: Yup @Notsileous and then from third activity i want to create pdf from the info i get

Comment: and if i save doc activity first and then personal activity i get this pdf https://48h.pics/SirkiS30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send data to `FirstActivity` to `ThirdActivity` by using `intent`, You can send data to `FirstActivity` to `SecondActivity` by intent again you have to get the data on `SecondActivity` and again have to send data to `ThirdActivity` otherwise you will get null data .

**Solution 1:** Either you can create a Constant class and store data on constant class and get data from Constant class **or,** Create a POJO class and set Data to POJO  and make it Serializable send POJO class to Next of your Activity.

Reference Code :

```
public class Constants {

    public static ArrayList<LoadDataResult> data = new ArrayList<LoadDataResult>();

  }
```

When you will get data from User by Edittext get and set to POJO which in Constant class and where do you want to get create reference and get data.

**Solution 2 :** You have 8 Activities and you want to save all information and create PDF file from **MainActivity.java**

**Here is the solution :** Use `SharedPreference` to save Data , Save data from all of your different activities, and in Your **MainActivity** when you want just getData from `SharePreference` , by using this also there is not chance of lost of Data.

**FirstActivity.java :**

```
 SharedPreferences pref;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

     pref = (this.getApplicationContext()).getSharedPreferences("USER_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);

     editor = pref.edit();
                                            editor.putBoolean("login_status", true);
                                            editor.putString("CODE", "" + String.valueOf(obj.get("code")));
                                            editor.putString("NAME", "" + String.valueOf(obj.get("message")));
                                            editor.putString("USER_ID", "" + String.valueOf(obj.get("user id")));
                                            editor.commit();
```

**SecondActivity.java :**

```
     SharedPreferences pref;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

         pref = (this.getApplicationContext()).getSharedPreferences("USER_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);



                                                editor.putString("ADDRESS", "" + String.valueOf(obj.get("message")));
                                                editor.putString("PHONE", "" + String.valueOf(obj.get("user id")));
                                                editor.commit();
```

**MainActivity.java :** When you want to get All Data

```
SharedPreferences pref;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

         pref = (this.getApplicationContext()).getSharedPreferences("USER_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);

String name = pref.getString("NAME", "");
String userId = pref.getString("USER_ID", "");
String address = pref.getString("ADDRESS", "");
String phone= pref.getString("PHONE", "");
```

Comment: I was just formulating this myself, you cant chain the data together, you are overwriting each time, either pull and pass the pass the old data with the new or store in another fashion.

Comment: Better solution here is to send Data to SecondActivity and get Data in Second Activity And Send Both(First & Second Activity) Data to ThirdActivity .

Comment: Actually i don't have 2 activities i have 8 Activities

Comment: @SaadZahoor , when user fill the data on EditText after what do you want , Can you Explain

Comment: its simple user go to first activity and fill data and hit save in save button the data goes to the main activity.When user hit save the user goes back to the list of activities(i.e main activity) like add personal info , add experience , add hobbies (these are all different activities) now user go to each activity and add info and hit enter (the data goes to main activity) and user get back to the main activity >.in main activity i have a button to generate pdf using itext .this is what i want to do buy falling into the prob

Comment: Now , i understand @SaadZahoor

Comment: thank for you effort i already tried this method .. its just gave other errors ..NULLPointExcetion something like that ,, I am thinking to use SQLDatabase  to store and get the info .. BTW thanks

Comment: I will try this and let you know ,, tell me one thing u define spref in each activity but when i leave activity is not spref will be destroyed .. ??

Comment: like the saveInstance

Comment: Use shared preference no issue at all

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for .. O God .. Thanks @Abhishekkumar

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by simply send the pojo which contains all of the data in each activity. You only need to pass to pojo from one activity to another activity.

You need to create pojo to something like this:

```
public class Info implements Serializable {

  private String firstName;
  private String born;
  private String nationality;
  //etc ...

  // Data from another activity:
  private String passportNumber;
  private String idCard;
  private String license;
  //etc ...

  // Data from another activity:
  // etc ...

  // Constructor

  // Setter and Getter
}
```

Then you can send the data intent with:

```
public void getting_data_from_fields_and_sending_on_click_listner () {
  Intent sendingData = new Intent (Personal_Information_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class);
  Info info = new Info();
  info.setFirstName(fullName.getText().toString());
  info.setBorn(born.getText().toString());
  info.setNationality(nationality.getText().toString());
  // etc

  // Then attach the data to intent.
  sendingData.putExtra("info" , info);

  startActivity(sendingData);
}
```

Then you get the data info in another activity with:

```
private Info mInfo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  mInfo = (Info) intent.getSerializableExtra("info");
  ...
}
```

And set the data to the **Info** pojo again:

```
private void getting_data_from_fields_and_sending_on_click_listner() {

  Intent sendingData = new Intent (Documentation_Activity.this , Selecting_Activity.class);

  mInfo.setPassportNumber(passportNumber.getText().toString());
  mInfo.setIdCard(idCardNumber.getText().toString());
  mInfo.setLicense(licenceNumebr.getText().toString());
  // etc ...

  sendingData.putExtra("info" , mInfo);
  startActivity(sendingData);
}
```

With the all the above codes, you can safe yourself from headache for remembering all of the **extra** keys. You also only need to maintain one object, which is the Info object, for all of your activity.

Comment: One thing confuse me should i set my constructor empty or should i pass some thing .. like i am using both intent and constructor ??

Comment: Usually, I'm using the default constructor. But inside the default constructor, I'm setting all the the initial values, something like `public Info() {
  this.firstName = "";
  this.born = "";
  this.nationality = "";
  // etc
}` so we have the default values for the object.

Comment: I really appreciate that but my problem remains no matter if i use this technique or mine that i was using ... The data just replace and i  get the latest one i don't no how to explain it .. i just got one data or i can say data form one activity instead of multiple activity ::

Comment: i tried the code works fine same as mine but i used to send data through intents only .. The problem is not in sending the data..if i only use one activity and send data to other activity to create pdf that's work fine . but whenever i send data from multiple activity i only get one activity data the rest is null ::

Comment: Did you send the data in the following order: FirstActivity->SecondActivity->ThirdActivity->FourthActivity->...? If you sent the data using the order, you need to create the pojo object first in the FirstActivity. For the remaining activity, you need to keep using the Object and only altering the value for related data. Don't create the object.